# Waving your shirt to cool yourself off

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word (or short expression) for "the act of waving your shirt, in order to cool yourself off"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Flabellation](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/150156/flabellation)**:  The act of keeping cool by use of a fan or **fan-like instrument**.

**Flabellation**: The act of keeping fractured limbs cool by the use of a fan or **some other contrivance**. Dunglison. [1913 Webster] …

Comment: .."Fan or fan like instrument".. *shirt* fits neither..

Comment: Though the word 'flabelliform' is defined as shaped like a fan, I believe the implication of a fan-like instrument is anything that can be used as a fan, and not a specific rhipidate type instrument.

Comment: Using _flabellation_ in casual conversation would probably result mostly in blank stares and question marks on your listeners’ faces—assuming they don't just think you meant _flagellation_ and consider you quite certifiable.

Comment: Doesn't a shirt qualify as *some other contrivance*. Choose this answer, already.

Comment: For some reason footballers will remove their shirt after scoring a goal and twirl it in a gesture of celebration. I am not sure why they do this, of all things, but it seems instinctive, perhaps because a shirt is uncomfortable to wear when it is dripping in sweat. It is however an action guaranteed to attract a yellow card; but I am equally at a loss to understand why that is. There is no group of people like football administrators for making rules for the sake of it.

Answer (score 4):

Shirts generally don't make good fans, and you would likely work up more of a sweat trying to cool yourself by waving your shirt around. But if you need to do that, *fanning himself with his shirt* is correct.

Sometimes people *pluck at their shirts* because they feel hot and sweaty.